# How to move the triangle under the anchor element using transform property?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add the triangle pointer directly in the middle of the anchor element. I tried using the transform property but its not working for the x coordinate:

```
    .navigation-bar > a {
     float:right;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
     margin-right: 15px;
     height: 60px;
     color: white;
     line-height: 70px;
     font-weight: bolder;
     font-size: 12px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     position: relative;
     padding: 3px;
     }
    
     .navigation-bar > a:hover:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
    
      transform: translateX(350px);
      transform: translateY(40px);
    
      width: 0px;
      height: 7px;
    
      border-left: 5px solid transparent;
       border-right: 5px solid transparent;
       border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that way....

```css
.navigation-bar>a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  background: red;
}

.navigation-bar>a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <a href="#">html</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use the transform property without specifying top left and right.

Comment: Other than using top width and height, how to use transform property?